# Como despertar a tela somente tocando na tela do android

Tags: android

Seria possível despertar um aparelho com Sistema Operacional Android apenas tocando sua tela, sem pressionar nenhum botão físico como Power ou Home, tal como no **Nexus 5** e **LG G2**, nos quais um duplo toque na tela apagada os despertam.

Necessito de algo já existente que realize esse procedimento pois desconheço meios de como proceder. Deixo [um link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBGKSMpjgxo) para um vídeo do Youtube demonstrando o recurso em melhores detalhes.

Comment: Vocês têm certeza de que isto é amplo demais? Não parece.

Comment: @bfavaretto Concordo que não é amplo demais, mas ainda acho que deva estar fechada, pois não me parece uma dúvida sobre programação, e sim uma busca por códigos prontos que realizem a tarefa que ele deseja

Comment: Pra mim isto é fora de contexto, de amplo não tem nada. Está bem específica, mas não é uma questão de programação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é uma funcionalidade do Android convencional e sim de uma ROM modificada chamada ElementalX. Na descrição do vídeo há um link para a [versão dessa ROM para o Nexus 5](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/orig-development/kernel-elementalx-n5-0-23-t2519607) (funcionalidade *doubletap2wake*). Essa funcionalidade inclusive consome mais bateria quando habilitada, pois a CPU do dispositivo não entra em *sleep mode* pouco tempo depois da tela desligar, tendo que ficar ativa para detectar os toques na tela.

Comment: Certo, mas programar algo como no tipo, despertar a tela com 2 toques na tela não é possível, digo, sem o consumo de bateria exagerada? Porque, vi um LG G2 com a mesma função do Nexus 5 e não me aparenta consumir bateria assim. Com isso precisava desenvolver um meio de despertar o aparelho com o toque na tela.

Comment: Provavelmente não. Quem vai tratar os eventos de toque de tela é a CPU, que precisa já estar acordada (por meio de uma Wake Lock) para fazer esse tratamento. E vale lembrar que o LG G2 é um dos aparelhos com maior capacidade de bateria do mercado hoje.